# Firebird com serviço restfull e web api em C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restful, integração, firebird-2.5

Olá, dentro de um projeto me deparei com a seguinte situação, necessito replicar informações de um db Firebird Desktop para um db SQL Server Web, como ambas as arquiteturas não conversam entre si, a solução encontrada é uma aplicação web api e trabalhar com JSON, perfeito em partes, me deparei com a situação de como efetuar a conexão entre ambos os bancos de dados, é necessário criar uma aplicação local que conecte ao Firebird e encaminhe as informações para a web api, ou essa conexão é possível de ser feita na própria web api? se alguém tiver alguma dica para me dar, ou link de algum fórum ou algo assim que trate sobre o assunto, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo própio Web Api você consegue conectar no firebird.
Vê se esse libk te ajuda : http://johntomaselli.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/mvc-4-firebird-ef-41-and-database-first.html